# Creating dynamic component in ng-container, add ng-template and monitor ngModel

Tags: angular, custom-component, ng-template, ng-container

I've created a dynamic component that I can inject templates to it from the outside. My goal is to be able to inject any template, duplicate those templates inside the component and 2 way data bind to it in order to get data changes.

It looks something like that:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-container',
  templateUrl: './custom-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-container.component.css']
})
export class CustomContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() addButtonLabel: string;
  
  templates: Array<TemplateRef<any>> = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.templates.push(this.template);
  }
}
```

The HTML,I have an `add button` button to add more templates to itself dynamically and I have a `trash button` to delete templates:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let template of templates; let index = index; let last = last;">
    <button type="button" (click)="templates.splice(index, 1);" class="trash-button"></button>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context:{index:index}"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
<div (click)="templates.push(template)" class="add-button">{{addButtonLabel}}</div>
```

I use this component like this:

```js
<app-custom-container" [template]="tpl" addButtonLabel="ADD TEMPLATE"  addButtonClass="add-butto"></app-custom-container>
<ng-template #tpl let-index="index">
    <p-dropdown [options]="mylist" [autoWidth]="false" [(ngModel)]="myData[index]" name="myName{{index}}"
        required>
    </p-dropdown>
</ng-template>
```

I'm using ng-prime, thus the `p-dropdown`.

So what I would want is to be able to create those dynamic components, inject any template to it and be able to duplicate this template withing this dynamic component. In addition, I would want the selected data from the drop down to be inserted to my data, thus the `ngModel`.

Problems I have:

- I am not sure that this is the best design for my goals. The `index` that is communicated back, seems pretty awkward to me.
- Basically it is working, except for the `splice` part. When I'm `splice`ing, the data model gets new indexes after the `container` is being rendered again and everything is a mess, the data doesn't `sit`s where it should. I thought about sending the data as well and have the component manage it, but I'm not sure that it's the right thing to do or even how to do it.

I would appreciate your advise and add info if something is not clear.

**Update 1:**
Add [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5NHzQCqzNnzL7HbkZ2ky?p=preview).

As you can see, I'm adding elements and when I try to delete them, it deletes from the bottom. I must know if my basic approach is good and then to figure how to delete and update my data array accordingly.

Comment: can you setup a plunker"?

Comment: Added plnkr, please see above @Maximus

Comment: cool, I'll take a look later

Comment: Seems you don't synchronize `myData` array with `templates`. Can you take a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/qRG4DjC0JbE8wm28sF6C?p=preview?

Comment: You can also read `TemplateRef` through `@ContentChild` if you will declare template inside `app-custom-container` tag

Comment: @yurzui - thanks it seems to work! I thought that the face that I'm "sending back" the `index` in the `context` should update `myData`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. `myData` is array that has it's own items

Comment: @yurzui- do you think that I should send `myData` to the custom component and let it handle the add/remove by itself? I just want to avoid to implementation of `added` and `deleted` for every `custom-container` call. WDYT?

Comment: Yeah it worked: https://plnkr.co/edit/VoGXCFFNz2DxzOEorwDI?p=preview
Thanks a lot for your help. Please put your answer as an answer so I would be able to mark it as answered :)